# The name for equations/problems like "How many four-digit numbers have four different digits (without a leading $0$)?"

Tags: combinatorics

I'm not very quick at these kinds of problems so I want to improve on them. But I don't know what topics to search for.

Should I be searching for significant figures + base arithmetic?

> How many four-digit decimal numbers are made from four (4) different digits between $0$ and $9$?
>
> Here, a four-digit decimal number has a non-zero leading digit.

Comment: You might have better luck searching for *combinatorics* problems. The "how many ways can you arrange these symbols in these ways" style of problem falls squarely in combinatorics territory.

Comment: @sambo Thanks a million.

Comment: Is a combinatorial problem. Multiplicative and additive principle can be useful for this type of problems.

Comment: This particular problem is an example of a [permutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation).  Counting the number of permutations is based on the [Multiplication Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product), one of the key ideas in combinatorics.

Comment: Thanks guys. Coming from a non-CS background it's very interesting to actually find out the names of all of these topics. Binary Arithmetic, Euclidian Arithmetic etc. I have been able to solve most of them on my own but need a lot of practice so plugging these topics into Youtube is gold.

Comment: The name for such problems is "common sense".

Answer (score 1):

As you were told in the comments, the topic is called **permutation**. But, as you don't the whole set of digit numbers some may refer to that as an **variation** on some texts. I have read that a **variation** is a permutation of r elements from n. By this definition we could get the closed formula,

$$V(n,r)=\frac{n!}{(n-r)!}.$$

This term is introduced because some people link the idea of permutation to the **factorial**.

To solve your example this "new" idea should be use with the **multiplication principle** as follows,
$$9\times V(9,3)$$
First you choose the first digit (9 possibilities) and then reduce the problem to choose a number with three digits (it could be a zero leading digit in this case).